# What should I improve my telescope kit to see more details of Moon?

Tags: the-moon, telescope, jupiter, saturn

What should I improve my telescope kit to see more details of Moon?
I have the gskyer telescope of 60mm aperture and 350mm focal length.
my eyepieces are 10mm,25mm. 
and I have x3 Barlow.
my best viewing of the Moon when I combine the Barlow with 10mm eyepiece.
I want to see deep details of the moon, by the way, this helps me to zoom in more for the planets like Mars, Jupiter, and Saturn.
any help?

Comment: This is very similar to your other question about seeing Jupiter.  As any answers from that could solve your problems with this as well, I'd suggest waiting for some answers to that one.

Answer (score 1):

The theoretical resolution of a telescope - and the maximum useful magnification that you can use - increases with aperture (That's the diameter of the main mirror or lens, and not the f-ratio (which is what photographers usually mean by aperture)). As a rough guide, the typical everyday maximum magnification is around the same as the aperture in mm (and is achieved with an eyepiece of focal length equal to the scope's f ratio).

Given good seeing conditions (steady atmosphere, which can be rare) you can push the magnification to around twice that (with half the eyepiece focal length, or by using a barlow) - which is what manufacturers usually quote as the maximum magnification.

As magnification goes up, the brightness of the view goes down, since you're spreading the same amount of light over a larger area. (Increasing aperture increases the light gathering area; doubling the aperture catches four times as much light, so increasing the aperture allows brighter views at the same magnification. This is important for fainter objects, but the moon is bright enough that you don't usually have problems even with small scopes)

So the best way to see more detail is to switch to a good quality, larger aperture scope.